# How to insert select data into input when do not have ID or class

Tags: javascript

How to insert select data into input when do not have ID or class.

**HTML code:**

```
<input type="text"  name="employed_since" data-validators="required validate-date2"/>

<select id="field3" size="0" style="display: inline-block;">
<option value="" class="">.................
<select id="field4"  size="0" style="display: inline-block;">
<option value="" class="">J
```

**This is example js code when i have ID:**

```
$('field3').addEvent('change', function() {

    if (this.selectedIndex != 0 && $("field4").selectedIndex != 0) {
        $("employed_since").value = this.value + $("field4").options[$("field4").selectedIndex].value;
        $("employed_since").fireEvent('change');
        }

});

$('field4').addEvent('change', function() {
    if (this.selectedIndex != 0 && $("field3").selectedIndex != 0) {
        $("employed_since").value = $("field3").options[$("field3").selectedIndex].value + this.value;
        $("employed_since").fireEvent('change');
        }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any css selector to grab an element using jQuery. For example

```
$('input[name=employed_since]').val = '1984';
```

Will set the value of the input element with the name `employed_since`.

See this [reference to all the available css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp). I usually like to open up the javascript console on the page I'm working with and just trying out the selection until I get it just right.

The command using the native `querySelector` function would be very similar.

```
document.querySelector('input[name=employed_since]').value = '1984';
```

Comment: Think you mean `.val('1984')`, or use `querySelector()` and you're golden.

Comment: Yeah, I was just copying the askers code exactly. In order for it to be less confusing... but maybe that's MORE confusing :)

Comment: I use this querySelector().  and help me. :-)

Comment: Hi Nemanja, do you mean that in your code you did something like `var $ = docunent.querySelector;`?

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the change event to the `form` since that event bubbles. In your event handler, the `this` variable references the form. The handler also receives a single argument called `event`. The `event.target` property is the form field that just changed.

To access form fields without the Id property, simply use `this.fields.field_name` where your replace "field_name" with the value of a form field's name attribute.